# Rails internationalization

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

I am following the guide from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html to add several translation to my page, using the "http://mysite/**en**/page" and everything is working fine, except that I am not being able to add the language switcher to my page.

I'd like to go to the same page I am showing but using the other language. For that, I presume I should use the same url, except for the :locale parameter. How to do that with a link_to call?

Really dummy question but I've just started in Rails and I am stuck with it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To link to the current page with a different locale, use url_for with only the locale parameter:

```
url_for(:locale => "de")
```

This will preserve any other URL parameters. So for example, to provide a link to the German version of the current page:

```
link_to "German version", url_for(:locale => "de")
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use an extra method to setup user's local seamless (it will be stored in cookie/sessions) as

*controllers/application.rb*

```
before_filter :set_user_language
def set_user_language
  I18n.locale = current_user.language if logged_in?
end
```

please see more details [at Railscasts.com](http://railscasts.com/episodes/138-i18n?autoplay=true)

Comment: that is good too. But right now my page is really simple. Hopefully will be adding new functionalities soon! thanks!